# Bazel Link .so libraries located in a completely different, very remote folder

Tags: c++, cmake, tensorflow, bazel, lcm

Folks,

I am trying to link .h and static libraries into my tensorflow program. My headers are in

```
/usr/local/include/lcm
```

And static/shared libraries (.so, etc.) in

```
/usr/local/lib
```

But Bazel complains they don't exist, or that it cannot find them. Here is my code on my BUILD file:

```
package(default_visibility = ["//tensorflow:internal"])
licenses(["notice"])  # Apache 2.0
exports_files(["LICENSE"])

# LCM shared libraries path
cc_library(
    name = "lcm_lib",
    srcs = glob([
        "*.so",
    ]),
    copts = ["-L/usr/local/lib"],
    linkopts = ["-pthread", "-shared"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

# LCM header libraries path
cc_library(
    name = "lcm_headers",
    hdrs = glob([
        "include/**/*.h",
    ]),
    copts = ["-L/usr/local/include"],
    linkopts = ["-pthread"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

cc_binary(
    name = "myProject",
    srcs = [
        "main.cc",
    ],
    linkopts = ["-lm"],
    deps = [
        "//tensorflow/cc:cc_ops",
        "//tensorflow/core:framework_internal",
        "//tensorflow/core:tensorflow",
    ],
)

filegroup(
    name = "all_files",
    srcs = glob(
        ["**/*"],
        exclude = [
            "**/METADATA",
            "**/OWNERS",
            "bin/**",
            "gen/**",
        ],
    ),
    visibility = ["//tensorflow:__subpackages__"],
)
```

If I remove LCM related code (from both BUILD and main.cc), then my program builds and runs. When I include LCM, then I get errors saying that lcm::LCM::~LCM() is undefined, and that it cannot find the liblcm.so.
Now, my non-tensorflow code (or the majority of my project) is running cmake, and LCM and the rest of the libraries I need (openCV, etc.) can be found. I use commands in my CMakeList.txt like:

```
# search path for LCM header files
set(LCM_IncludeSearchPaths
  /usr/include/
  /usr/local/include/
  /opt/local/include
)
# search path for LCM static/dynamic libraries
set(LCM_LibrarySearchPaths
  /usr/lib/
  /usr/local/lib/
  /opt/local/lib/
)
find_path(LCM_INCLUDE_DIR
    NAMES lcm/lcm.h
    HINTS ${LCM_IncludeSearchPaths}
)   
FIND_LIBRARY(LCM_LIBS
  NAMES lcm
  HINTS ${LCM_LibrarySearchPaths}
  PATH_SUFFIXES lib
)
```

And it all works. But it does not work for tensorflow and Bazel

Here are my build and WORKSPACE files, located in the same directory:

This is my touched WORKSPACE file:

```
# LCM static libraries
new_local_repository(
    name = "lcm_libs",
    # pkg-config --variable=libdir x11
    path = "/usr/local/lib",
    build_file_content = """
cc_library(
    name = "liblcm",
    srcs = ["liblcm.so"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
""",
)

# LCM header files
new_local_repository(
    name = "lcm_headers",
    # pkg-config --variable=libdir x11
    path = "/usr/local/include",
    build_file_content = """
cc_library(
    name = "lcm",
    hdrs = glob([
        "lcm/*.h", "lcm/*.hpp",
    ]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
""",
)

# bind to a name to avoid using the "actual" format
#bind(
#    name = "liblcm",
#    actual = "@lcm_libs//:liblcm",
#)
#bind(
#    name = "lcm",
#    actual = "@lcm_headers//:lcm",
#)
#
```

And my BUILD:

```
# Description:
#   Tensorflow C++ inference example for labeling images.

package(default_visibility = ["//tensorflow:internal"])
licenses(["notice"])  # Apache 2.0
exports_files(["LICENSE"])

cc_binary(
    name = "facialFatigue",
    srcs = [
        "main.cc",
    ],
    linkopts = ["-lm"],
    deps = [
        "//tensorflow/cc:cc_ops",
        "//tensorflow/core:framework_internal",
        "//tensorflow/core:tensorflow",
        "@lcm_libs//:liblcm",
        "@lcm_headers//:lcm",
    ],
)

filegroup(
    name = "all_files",
    srcs = glob(
        ["**/*"],
        exclude = [
            "**/METADATA",
            "**/OWNERS",
            "bin/**",
            "gen/**",
        ],
    ),
    visibility = ["//tensorflow:__subpackages__"],
)
```

Sorry for the long question :-(

Answer (score 1):

Bazel executes action (in your case C++ compile action) in a sandbox, to ensure the hermeticity. This is needed to be correct when inputs of the action change. Therefore you have to tell Bazel about **all** the inputs, including the system ones.

But of course you can depend on system libraries, take a look at [local_repository rule](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/be/workspace.html#local_repository). You might also find this [example in bazel-discuss@](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/bazel-discuss/Ndd820uaq2U/gsssAZyBAAAJ) thread helpful.

Comment: I get errors:ERROR: /home/mario/tensorflow_HY/tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/MYPROJECT/cpp/BUILD:39:1: no such package '@lcm_headers//': error loading package 'external': The repository named 'lcm_headers' could not be resolved and referenced by '//tensorflow/examples/MYPROJECT/cpp:PROJECT'.

Comment: see my WOKSPACE and new BUILD files above. Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Is the workspace file you pasted in the root of the repo? Maybe you have 2 workspace files, one in the root, one in the tensorflow/examples/MYPROJECT/. Try to edit the root one. Other than that it looks ok..